# Parse HTTP Header from fsockopen with PHP?

Tags: php, http, header, fgets

I have a script set up that for reasons of necessity gets both the HTTP Response header and then content of a GET request using fsock.

```
function checkUrl($host,$url,$port) {
$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: $host\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $response = fgets($fp, 1024);
        print(substr($response,9,3));
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
}
```

I call it and get all the proper data back if I simply echo it all out. But actually all I need to return from the function is the HTTP STATUS Code.

i.e. 404 or 200 or 301 etc

But the code above gives the error code sure, but then with a load of gibberish at the end which I don't understand when I have limited to 3 chars!

e.g.

```
404, 2BM_n: Encype HThe tp-me=srcsrclanstaPre> lanmg=[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10[11[12 swt.i> ypeeleamiize#99eco#66ade#33izeine#CCize { #66izeeig tmardespath=th=th=th=th=th=th=spardeolordeignign bocol widwidwid col bler> td Sorabl> e> rdeolordespath=th=th= bo spardeoloe="lanSen>
```

Which leads me to believe that my response is actually more complex than just a string right? Something special with the header or am I misunderstanding how fgets is working? Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are printing out that substring for *every* block of 1024 characters instead of just the first. The solution is to not do the loop. Change this:

```
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $response = fgets($fp, 1024);
    print(substr($response,9,3));
}
```

To just this:

```
$response = fgets($fp, 1024);
print(substr($response,9,3));
```

Or even just this, really, since you only need the first 13 characters, not the first 1024:

```
$response = fgets($fp, 13);
print(substr($response,9,3));
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, bozo thinking on my part :) It IS important that the full page is fetched like a browser would fetch it in order for it to be compiled properly, thus I was thinking I needed to process the entire file.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment you're iterating over each line of the header/response even though you're only interested in the first line. Try this instead:

```
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $response = fgets($fp, 1024);
    $code = substr($response,9,3);
    if (is_numeric($code)) {
        $break;
     }
}

// $code should contain the response code
```

If you're only interested in the headers and not the response I'd suggest that you make a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` one.

Unless there's a really compelling reason not to I'd suggest that you make this request using `CURL` rather than trying to handle all of the low level stuff within your PHP app logic.

Comment: Yes I have looked into the curl option a few times, but as the code is to be used in basically 'warming' up a server ready for release to a LOT of hits/sec ... the opening of sockets seems to make the load balancers work better from the start along with other things. And I DO need to get the full content of the page, otherwise not all the servlets will be initialised, meaning a crash as soon as we let the public in :)

Comment: OK - That's surprising. It's hard to see any scientific reason as to why CURL/raw sockets would work differently. The request via CURL will also have to create a socket, write out the request to it and then read the response in exactly the same manner.